# Moving dot files using bash and creating symlinks

Tags: bash

Trying to move selected `dotfiles` from `~` directory into new directory `dotfiles` and create `symbink`, with this code:

```
  1 #!/bin/bash.
  2 # This file moves selected files to newly created .dotfile folder and creates symbolic synblinks.
  3 
  4 # STEPS:.
  5 # 1. create and array of with .dotfiles elements.
  6 # 2. create a new directory .dotfiles if this directory does not exits.
  7 # 3. move selected .dotfiles from step 1 into directory created in step 2.
  8 # 4. create symbolic links for all .dotfiles from step 1.
  9 # 5. initialize a git repo.
 10 
 11 # 1. declare an array with .dotfiles element for versioning:.
 12 declare -a Dotfiles=('bash_profile' 'bashrc' 'gitconfig' 'gitignore' 'profile' 'vimrc' 'vimrc.after' )
 13 
 14 # inform the user and print the whole array on the screen:
 15 echo 'going to move the following selected .dotfiles:'
 16 echo ${Dotfiles[@]}
 17 
 18 # 2. create a variable for new directory for storing dotfiles..
 19 dir = ~/dotfiles
 20 cd ~ && mkdir -p $dir
 21 echo 'directory created'
 22 
 23 # move selected dotfiles to new directory .dotfiles
 24 
 25 for dotfile in "${Dotfiles[@]}";do
 26   echo "moving $dotfile into directory $dir"
 27   mv ~/.$dotfile $dir
 28   echo "creating symblik for $dotfile"
 29   ln -s $dir/$dotfile ~/.$dotfile
 30 done
 31 echo 'done'
```

When I run it, new directory is created, but original dotfiles are not moved and symblink are not running as well.

**Questions are**

1. What is missing in this code?
2. Do you have some suggestions for refactoring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assignment to `dir` should be

```
dir=~/dotfiles
```

The spaces you have cause it to be interpreted as a call to the `dir` command with 2 arguments. The `mv` command subsequently tries to move the files to the root directory (since `$dir/` expands to `/`).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
25 for dotfile in "${Dotfiles[@]}";do
26   echo "moving $dotfile into directory $dir"
27   mv ~/.$dotfile $dir/
28   echo "creating symblik for $dotfile"
29   ln -s $dir/$dotfile ~/.$dotfile
30 done
```

though there are other ways to resolve. This better not be homework :)